# GoogleApiClient changes location query interval for no reason

Tags: android, google-api-client

I'm using fusedLocationApi for positioning in my Android app. Here is code for location request:

```
private void createLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setInterval(5000)
                .setFastestInterval(5000)
                .setSmallestDisplacement(0.0f)
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
```

In most cases app works fine and every 5 second onLocationChanged get called with valid location data.

But some users expirience a wierd bug. For some reason time interval becomes 1h 23 mins. There is no place in code that alters the initial 5000ms value for this interval.

I've broken my mind already. What can be a reason for such a behavior? Maybe users losts satellites or internet - but googleApiClient will invoke onLocationChanged() anyway. Or maybe when device is low on energy - API decides to query GPS module less frequently?? So - i'm realy stuck with this = please, help.

Comment: Please check out this link, it maybe helpful.
[Google play services location stops location updates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19491726/2736964)

Comment: Thx, i think i'll use described hack and continue to investigate.

Comment: Request object looks to be good. As displacement is set to zero, onLocationChanged() should happen every 5 seconds as setInterval() is set to 5 mins. Is that 1h 23mins same for all users ? How frequently the issue is seen ? There may not be a GPS signal or network as well so they did not receive, I believe.

Comment: Yes - this mysterious 1h 23m interval appears on two different devices. During past 2 weeks only 2 users was affected.

Comment: All location fetching code runs in background or only when the app is visible?

Comment: All location operations runs via static object (LocationProvider singleton), that supposed to live until app process dies (as i think).